# Splitting Styled-Components into multiple files but export them as one file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

When I was building my application, I didn't realize that I am going to end up with more than a hundred styled components. Consequently, I was putting them in the same file like this:

```
export const StyledTabs = styled(Tabs)`
  display: inline-flex !important;
  margin-left: 15% !important;
`;

export const StyledTab = styled(Tab)`
  display: inline-flex !important;
  margin-left: 0% !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
`;
```

... And the application imports them like this:

```
import { StyledTabs, StyledTitle } from "StyledComponents";
```

I want to split the `StyledComponents.js` file into multiple files by, for example, UI logic (header, footer, containers, etc..) but somehow, import them back into `StyledComponents.js` so I don't have to refactor the entire application.

Is something like this possible:

**HeaderSC.js**

```
export const StyledTabs = styled(Tabs)`
  display: inline-flex !important;
  margin-left: 15% !important;
`;

export const StyledTab = styled(Tab)`
  display: inline-flex !important;
  margin-left: 0% !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
`;
```

**StyledComponents.js**

```
import { StyledTabs, StyledTitle } from "../styling/HeaderSC";
```

..and then the app still referring to `StyledTabs` or any other styled component from `StyledComponents.js` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a folder StyledComponents and inside that create a default import file index.js, from which all your exports will be facilitated.

In the very same folder create different files for different components like `StyledTabs.js` and `StyledTitle.js` then index.js of the very same folder you can do

```
export StyledTab from './StyledTab';
export StyleTitle from './StyledTitle';
```

This way your `import { StyledTab } from 'path/to/StyledComponents'` will work flawlessly

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like following this steps.

1) You create folder **Tabs**

2) Inside Tabs folder you create **index.js** and **styled.js** files.

In **index.js** file:

```
import {StyledTabs, StyledTitle } from "./styled
```

In **styled.js** file:

```
export const StyledTabs = styled(Tabs)`
  display: inline-flex !important;
  margin-left: 15% !important;
`;

export const StyledTab = styled(Tab)`
  display: inline-flex !important;
  margin-left: 0% !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
`;
```