# React - cannot export multiple files from index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am creating a styled-components with Atomic Design and I want to separate styled files into one folder and have one index.js to export all files. I have found that can be done like this way: [Splitting Styled-Components into multiple files but export them as one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754680/splitting-styled-components-into-multiple-files-but-export-them-as-one-file) but In my case when I want to export file inside `index.js`

```
export StyledClosestMeet from 'styledComponents/StyledClosestMeet.js';
```

I have error

> Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)

Inside styledComponents folder I have second file:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import variables from 'settings/variables';

const StyledClosestMeet = styled.div`
  color: ${variables.colorMain};
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
`;
```

And later I want to import that file inside Atom file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyledClosestMeet} from 'styledComponents/StyledClosestMeet';

const ClosestMeet = () => {
  return <StyledClosestMeet>Najbliższe spotkanie</StyledClosestMeet>;
};

export default ClosestMeet;
```

**I am using jsconfig "baseUrl": "./src"**

Comment: Ok I found issue: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-export-default-from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an index.js file to export both files like this:

```
export { default as Styled1 } from "./styled1";
export { default as Styled2 } from "./styled2";
```

and then import them like this:

```
import { Styled1, Styled2 } from "./styled/index";
```

Check out this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-spence-s0pj0)

Answer (score 0):

You've to export StyledClosestMeet

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import variables from 'settings/variables';

const StyledClosestMeet = styled.div`
  color: ${variables.colorMain};
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
`;

export { StyledClosestMeet }
```

And you can export StyledClosestMeet like below.

```
export { StyledClosestMeet } from 'styledComponents/StyledClosestMeet.js';
```